# Export xlsx file through executing scripts in SQL developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, xlsx

I know that we can use SPOOL command to export query result in CSV format from sql developer. However, I would like to export the query result as xlsx format instead of CSV format. Is there any command that I can use ??

Comment: Thank you for your help. At last, I use ssconvert on the server to convert the CSV file into xlsx file.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The best you can do is CSV via spool.

Or, if you're going to be exporting tables/views, you can use the sdcli to batch xlsx exports. I show this in detail [here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2018/11/scheduling-exports-of-your-data-using-the-cart/)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Developer you can export a gridresult by right-click -> export -> Format = "excel 2003+ ( xlsx ) ... but think you know this already.

Last time I created an XLSX file I used https://technology.amis.nl/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/as_xlsx18.txt

Probably I would use jasper or a different tool now.